# Calling derived class functions from within a vector (c++)

Tags: c++, class, function, vector

I have two classes:

```
class Object {
public:
  Object();
  virtual void update();
  virtual void draw();

private:

protected:
  int x, y, tick;

}
```

and

```
class Unit : public Object {
public:
  Unit();
  void update();

private:

protected:

}
```

I then define the constructors and functions in sepparate .cpp files.

Here's the definitions for Object:

```
Object::Object() {
  x = y = 0;
};

Object::update() {
  tick ++;
};

Object::draw() {
  // All my draw code is in here.
};
```

And Unit:

```
Unit::Unit() : Object() {

};

Unit::update() {
  Object::update();
  // Then there's a bunch of movement related code here.
};
```

Everything works fine individually, but I run into a problem when trying to call functions from within a vector.

```
vector<Object> objects;
```

I then do this in my void main():

```
for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i ++) {
  objects[i].update();
  objects[i].draw();
};
```

This draws everything fine, but it only calls the Object verson of update() not the version as defined by the derived class. Do I have to make a vector for each type that I derive from the Object class for it to work, or is there another way to call the derived functions?

Thanks in advance - Seymore

Comment: You shouldn't be doing anything in your *void main()*. The correct signature is *int main()*. Yes, your compiler probably happily accepts *void* as a return type, but it is still a good idea to use the correct signature as required by the C++ Standard, especially if you're new to the language and trying to learn it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it calls methods of `class Object`, because you have a vector of `class Object` objects:

```
vector<Object> objects; // stores instances of class Object
```

The possible solution is to use a vector of pointers:

```
vector<Object*> objects;
objects.push_back( new Unit() );
```

and then call though pointers:

```
for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i ++) {
    objects[i]->update();
    objects[i]->draw();
}
```

Comment: Wow. I didn't expect such a fast answer. This solved my problem as far as I can tell. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Seymore: You're welcome and don't forget to take care of those objects created with `new` later.

Comment: What about if I'm using an already instantiated object? Like: SubObject sub; vector<Object*> objects; objects.push_back(sub);Then do I need a smart ptr?

Comment: @AaronH.: You'd better not use one here, because the smart ptr destructor will destroy the object, then the object's destructor will be run again which will lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use object oriented polymorphism in C++ (with the meaning : you have a base class and derived classes and at runtime you can come across any off those) you must use pointers.

```
vector<Object *> objects;
```

That means manual memory management (but you can use shared_pointers or http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html), and possibly a very slight loss of performance (because of one extra dereferencing and v-table, however you shouldn't really care about it). And don't forget to make your methods virtual ;)

I think this is why I rarely use on my daily work object oriented programming as I learned it at school ;) I use heritage, but don't mix mother and daugther classes in the same containers (and I use templates for many interfaces).