# Calling member functions of objects vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

So I have a vector declared like so:

```
vector <Game *> games;
```

and I have a function in the `Game` class like so:

```
public:

    // Rest of .h

    void hello(){
        cout << "hello" << endl;
    }
```

and I'm trying to iterate over my `games` vector using an iterator, and call the `hello()` function each time:

```
vector <Game *>::const_iterator it_games = games.begin();

for (it_games = games.begin(); it_games != games.end(); it_games++) {
    *it_games->hello();
}
```

but I keep getting this error when I try to compile:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘void summary(std::vector<Game*, std::allocator<Game*> >, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string)’:
main.cpp:56: error: request for member ‘hello’ in ‘* it_games. __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator-> [with _Iterator = Game* const*, _Container = std::vector<Game*, std::allocator<Game*> >]()’, which is of non-class type ‘Game* const’
```

Any idea what's going on/how I can get my desired functionality?

Comment: There's a pretty decent chance you want `std::vector<Game>`.

Comment: I have `using namespace std;` implemented

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence : Of particular interest is the relative precedence of operators `*` and `->`

Comment: Plus I should mention that my objects/vectors are being instantiated correctly. The problem comes when I try to access a member function/variable in he iterator loop.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, so you're saying I want something like `(*it_games)->hello()`?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, that worked. If you want to write up an answer I'll check it

Comment: @ConnorBlack, I was more concerned about the pointer.

Comment: @chris, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270540/calling-derived-class-functions-from-within-a-vector-c

Comment: @ConnorBlack, If you have polymorphism and dynamically allocate these, I recommend a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Game>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator*` has lower precedence than `operator->`.  So this:

```
*it_games->hello();
```

should be this:

```
(*it_games)->hello();
```

Comment: or this: `it_games->hello();`

Comment: @Connor Black: Correct, because it_games is an iterator over pointers, not a pointer itself

Comment: @ConnorBlack Right. I was mistaken, sorry! :)

Answer (score 2):

`->` has precedence, so the it_games pointer is not dereferenced before hello().

Change

```
*it_games->hello();
```

to

```
(*it_games)->hello();
```